# Update SharePoint custom directory item person html to have delve profile linked

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, delve

How do you update the html of the "directoryitemperson.html" within the SharePoint people search result page so that the user's name links to the corresponding user's delve profile?

but how do you get that to work?

Display name section:

```
<div id="NameField">
<!--#_ 
                                           var encodedName = (has_pn == true) ? $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.PreferredName) : $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.YomiDisplayName);
                                           var displayName = Srch.U.getSingleHHXMLNodeValue(hhProps, "preferredname");
                                           if ($isEmptyString(displayName)) { displayName = encodedName }
_#-->
                                           <div id="NameValue" class="ms-srch-ellipsis ms-textLarge">
                                               _#= displayName =#_
                                           </div>
                                       </div>
```

Email section:

```
if(has_email == true) {
_#-->
                                            <div id="EmailField">
<!--#_ 
                                                var encodedEmail = $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.WorkEmail);
                                                var displayEmail = Srch.U.getSingleHHXMLNodeValue(hhProps, "workemail");
                                                if ($isEmptyString(displayEmail)) { displayEmail = encodedEmail }
_#--> 
                                                <div id="EmailValue" class="ms-srch-ellipsis" title="_#= encodedEmail =#_">                                                                                         
                                                
                                                <a href="mailto:_#=uEmail=#_">_#= displayEmail =#_</a>                                                

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
<!--#_ 
                                        }
```

used: https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3442990/Hyperfish_EmployeeDirectory_Guide.pdf?utm_campaign